# How would I search a .txt file for something between <> python

Tags: python, variables

I want to search a text file for info that is between brackets like so.

```
<fg="blue"><bg="red">
```

I would want to get the `fg="blue"`.

Then I would want to store the `"blue"` in a variable any clues how I could do this?

Comment: Is this textfile full html?

Comment: No there would be something in a text file that says <fg="blue"> and I want to store what is in the brackets in a variable but how would I get it? @timgeb

Comment: use regular expression

Comment: Do you also want 'bg="red"'? It's between angle brackets as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for this simple case, you can use a regexp.

```
import re
with open('myfile', 'r') as f:
    f = f.read()
    # use matches_a or matches_b depending on what you actually want
    matches_a = re.findall(r'<([^=]+=\"[^"]+\")>', f)
    matches_b = re.findall(r'<[^=]+=\"([^"]+)\">', f)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '<fg="blue"><bg="red">'
>>> re.findall(r'<([^=]+=\"[^"]+\")>',s)
['fg="blue"', 'bg="red"']
>>> re.findall(r'<[^=]+=\"([^"]+)\">',s)
['blue', 'red']
```

Comment: after I get the variable it looks like this ["foreground='red'"] how would I use that with self.Cont.config() I have tried storing it in a variable and putting the variable in the config but it did not work. how would I do this?

Comment: @cdw100100 Your question is too broad to answer in a comment, I have no idea what `self.Cont.config()` refers to. Please open a new question and include all the information needed to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Your example strings look like XML.  I suggest you Google search for "Python parse XML" or "Python parse HTML".

If it's XML you probably want ElementTree.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

If it's HTML you probably want BeautifulSoup.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Google will find you tutorials and documentation on both of the above.